# Is it possible to remove the little dropdown arrow in a JInternalFrame?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jinternalframe

I'm using a `JInternalFrame` and I want to remove the dropdown in the upper left of the frame, as it serves no purpose (I've disabled resizeable, closable, etc.)

[image: Persistent little dropdown arrow]

I don't see a property for this, and I don't want to remove the entire title bar, as the title is necessary. I've looked around online, and basically come up empty here.  I'm hoping it's something simple that I've just overlooked, as this is my first time using `JInternalFrame`, and I'm not exactly a GUI kind of guy to begin with.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
internalframe.setFrameIcon(null);
```

Edit: hack to remove system menu in Windows:

```
BasicInternalFrameUI ui = (BasicInternalFrameUI)internalFrame.getUI();
Container north = (Container)ui.getNorthPane();
north.remove(0);
north.validate();
north.repaint();
```

Comment: Works on Metal but not on Windows LAF.  With Windows the icon goes away but the menu still displays when the user clicks.

Comment: On Nimbus LAF, to also remove menu from right click action: `internalframe.setComponentPopupMenu(null);`

Answer (score 1):

The relevant `Icon` in [*The Synth Look and Feel*](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/synth.html), among the [*Nimbus Defaults*](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/_nimbusDefaults.html), appears to have this key:

```
InternalFrame:InternalFrameTitlePane:"InternalFrameTitlePane.menuButton".icon
```

You may be able to use the approach shown in [*A Synth Example*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/synthExample.html) to replace the `Icon`.

Answer (score 0):

```
setFrameIcon(anyBigImageThatCantBeDisplayed);
```

I´ve tried null parameter and got some visual issues...

[image]

So i added a big image(no background) that was already on my resource folder and the icon was no longer displayed as the menu...

[image]

Comment: Hello Wesos, thank you for your answer, however code only answers are discouraged. Can you edit this to explain why this code works and how it answers the question? Thanks!