# JInternalFrame - Remove top left drop down button

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jinternalframe

I have been looking through all properties and cant figure out how to remove it.  The GUI was generated with netbeans.  Does anybody know how to remove that pesky thing?

I don't have enough reputation to post the image, so here is a link to help understand the exact problem.

[image]

Comment: decorations for JInternalFrame is settable, read Oracle tutorial, API

Comment: @mKorbel But not for the system menu...

Answer (score 4):

As far as I know there is no API for this in the `JInternalFrame` class, but you can do that via the component UI:

The title bar of a `JInternalFrame` is a `Container`. You can get it from the `InternalFrameUI` by casting it to `BasicInternalFrameUI`. It's called `northPane`. The internal frame menu button is the first component in this title pane. You can simply remove it or make it invisible:

```
// Title or north pane of the internal frame:
Container pane = ((BasicInternalFrameUI) intFrame.getUI()).getNorthPane();

// And remove the button:
pane.remove(0);
// OR make it invisible:
pane.getComponent(0).setVisible(false);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this

```
internalframe.setFrameIcon(null);
```

And [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8144943/is-it-possible-to-remove-the-little-dropdown-arrow-in-a-jinternalframe) is a good example.

Comment: `setFrameIcon(null)` won't do it in Nimbus LaF.

Comment: Did you check the link that I've added?

Comment: Yes, I did. But it's not the `setFrameIcon(null)` that works but the rest of that accepted answer, which is the same I posted here.